# Nginx Config: nginx reverse proxy issue - with the links/site resources

Tags: python, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config

I have used an nginx reverse proxy pointing to different docker container,
https://example.com/app1 -> container1
https://example.com/app2 -> container2

Now the app1 site opens up and it is missing all the resources (CSS, js, etc). This is because of the URL mismatch.

Original resource at https://example.com/app1/style.css
The reverse proxied app shows resource at https://example.com/style.css

Similarly, if I click any link on the app1 URL will be pointing to (https://example.com/link1 instead of https://example.com/app1/link1)

Any help in solving this issue is really appreciated. Thanks

```
location /app1 {
  proxy_pass http://app1:8000/;
}

location /app2 {
  proxy_pass http://app2:8000/;
}

location /app3 {
  proxy_pass http://app3:8000;
}

location /app4 {
  proxy_pass http://app4:8890/;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your nginx config to your post?

Comment: The location for your reverse proxy is stepping one level too far, which is in your NGINX configuration.